# Resume download android

Tags: android, download

I was trying to look for some method which helps resuming download and i found the following code. What i don't understand what this line means...

```
if(ISSUE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS.intValue()==ECMConstant.ECM_DOWNLOADING)
```

what is ECMConstant here?

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
if(ISSUE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS.intValue()==ECMConstant.ECM_DOWNLOADING){
    File file=new File(DESTINATION_PATH);
    if(file.exists()){
         downloaded = (int) file.length();
         connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes="+(file.length())+"-");
    }
}else{
    connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
}
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
progressBar.setMax(connection.getContentLength());
 in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
 fos=(downloaded==0)? new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_PATH): new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_PATH,true);
 bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int x = 0;
while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
    bout.write(data, 0, x);
     downloaded += x;
     progressBar.setProgress(downloaded);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, is your problem solved? I have the same issue now..

Answer (score 0):

ECMConstant could be anything... There's no way to know what is if you don't have the full code or lib that ECMConstant come from.

If your doubt is how to resume download, everything you need to do is handle your Header, request property, or something your server needs to resume it, like this:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

            if (isResuming) {

                File fileToResume = new File(filePath);

                if (fileToResume.exists()) {

                    headers.put("Range", "bytes=" + fileToResume.length() + "-");
                }
            }
```

where isResuming is your flag to resume download or not.

Comment: This dsn't work for me, is their any other method to resume download.

Comment: This method just can be used if your download server support its.